# Name for a polygon which is laying on a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, polygons

Is there a name for a closed-loop polygon (2D, such as a circle, square, triangle, etc.) which is "draped" over a cylinder (3D)?

Picture Dali's famous painting, The Persistence of Memory.  If those clocks were of zero thickness, just circles melted over some 3D object, can you still call them polygons?  They wouldn't be quadrilaterals, because they themselves do not have a third dimension.

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: I do not think there is a name for these. I would call them closed curves. Polygons typically have sides which are straight line segments, so I do not think they should be called polygons, but it depends on what your definition of a polygon is.

Comment: I would tend to agree.  My hang up is that what I'm picturing are "2D" and "3D" at the same time, in that a 2D polygon is then bent into the third dimension.  I would actually want to define a polygon the way you did for my purposes, as a series of line segments forming a closed loop which does not self-intersect.  Then some or all of those straight lines become curved when melting/bending it over the cylinder.  Maybe there isn't a name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it a polygon. Since the cylinder can be rolled up from a plane without changing any locally measured angles, your polygon will unroll into a polygon in the plane.

The mathematics behind this is that the cylinder has Gaussian curvature $0$ and is a [developable surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface).